# I need to select the next webelement after refreshng the page? How can I do?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using the select class of selenium to select the webelement from the dropdown list. when I select the webelement and submit it..the page is refreshing and the webelement is reset to default value. I need to select the next webelement  after refreshng the page? How can I do

Comment: Hi Vinay, post some minimal code for people to understand what you've tried so far, and explain a bit as to what problem you'r e facing with the code

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_, _code trials_ and _error stack trace_ (if any)

Answer (score 0):

if the webpage is getting refreshed after your first select code execution then automatically then value of your earlier select action:

1. may be persisted.

if it is persisted then move to next select option. Please paste your code here and the error you are getting.

2. Reset to default.

if it is resetted to default ask your dev to change the code. because as per as I know there is no was of doing that in selenium.